# Possible repulsion effect due to Google Play Services if the user doesn't have a Google+ account yet

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm still in the process of developping a game and was excited when Google Play Services was announced during Google I/O and included it in my game a few days after. And it's great.
However, I fear that it may be a bad thing to use it since the user is requested to have a Google+ account to use Google Play Services and fear that the user will be repulsed if he hasn't a Google+ account yet and has to do all the process of creating one (a few steps, one being to type you first and last name, and your gender, and another sending you an email to welcome you) when launching my game for the first time.

Has anyone already published a game with Google Play Services and has an experience to share, be it good or bad? Did people react negatively to it in the reviews? Have the downloads decreased since its integration?

Since my game is fully multiplayer, I used the Android user's Google account to sign-in, so it made sense to make the use of Google Play Services automatic. For those who already published games with GPS, have you made it optional or mandatory?

Answer (score 2):

The best approach is to make the sign-in optional, but as you described, this is very important to your users, so I would make sure this is very clear on the app's description!

I published the [Minesweeper 3D](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wiirecords.minesweeper3d) with leaderboards and achievements, but they are optional. If the user doesn't sign-in he will see only his local scores.

I didn't notice any change on the number of installs/downloads, which is sad because we can't say anything about "google play games" on the app's description and then only apps they (Google) choose get attention from the public and millions of downloads.

But the number of sign-ins is extremely low, **only 10% is pressing the sign-in button** (clicks / total downloads).